# How to connect to other system db using jdbc type 4 driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a JDBC program which connects to my local system postgresql DB.

```
Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/LOCATIONS_INFO","postgres","password");
System.out.println("Connection Created");
```

This executes successfully. I also want to connect to a postgresql database which is on another system in the same LAN. When I replace localhost with the IP of the other system which i want to connect I get an exception.

Please help me how to achieve the connection.

Comment: At least post the exception + stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be problem with your configuration or network. At first check if PostgreSQL on another system is listening on port 5432 on all network interfaces. You can check it with `netstat` (of course you must run it on console of database server):

```
[mn@dbtest ~]# netstat -lnp | grep 5432
tcp   0  0 0.0.0.0:5432   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN   8484/postmaster
```

(if PostgreSQL works on Windows I suggest use of `TCPView` utility)

`0.0.0.0:5432` shows us that PostgreSQL is listening on port 5432 an all network interfaces.

Now you should check if PostgreSQL configuration allows connections from your IP. PostgreSQL uses `pg_hba.conf` file to allow/deny connections from various addresses. For example in my network entry:

```
host  all all 169.0.1.0/24   trust
```

allows all `169.0.1.*` machines to connect with PostgreSQL.

If such configuration allows you to connect then check firewalls on both your machine and database server.